# Unit tests fails with Null Pointer Exceptions with clover 3.1.8 however all go through clean with clover 4.0.2

Tags: code-coverage, clover, unit-testing

Ours is a multi module maven project and using clover2:instrument to generate instrumented fat jar. We evaluate functional test code coverage using the instrumented jar from command line, all steps mentioned below :

1. mvn clean install
2. mvn -P instrumentation clover2:instrument
3. Run functional test
4. mvn -P instrumentation clover2:aggregate
5. mvn -P instrumentation clover2:clover site

All unit tests passes with clover 4.0.2 however they fail with NPE when clover version 3.1.8 is used. We want to use older version because we have commercial license for it and not for newer version.
Kindly help.

I Cannot share the logs as this might offend my organisation policies. Sharing the excerpt

```
Tests run: 6, Failures: 6, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec <<< FAILURE!
com.***.*.*.*.*.drools.*.*************UnitTest.testKnowledgeAgentInitialization() Time elapsed: 0 sec <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.***.*.*.*.*.drools.*.*************UnitTest.testKnowledgeAgentInitialization(*************UnitTest.java:149)

Parent POM for clover:
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>instrumentation</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>instrumentation</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <dependencies>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.clover</groupId>
                <artifactId>clover</artifactId>
                <version>${version.clover}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clover2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.clover}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <license>${clover.license}</license>
                    <includesTestSourceRoots>false</includesTestSourceRoots>
                </configuration>
             <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>site</id>
                        <phase>pre-site</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

We are using Surefire to run Unit tests
    <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.14.1</version>
                <configuration>
                   <includes>
                        <include>**/*UnitTest.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <testNGArtifactName>none:none</testNGArtifactName>
                            <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports/testng</reportsDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-testng</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <junitArtifactName>none:none</junitArtifactName>
                            <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports/junit</reportsDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Adding additional stack from log although it don't really give much information

Running com.*.air.supply.*.*.drools.ruleengine.ApplyQueryValueThrottleEngineUnitTest
Tests run: 4, Failures: 4, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.27 sec <<< FAILURE!
com.*.air.supply.*.*.drools.ruleengine.ApplyQueryValueThrottleEngineUnitTest.testKnowledgeAgentInitialization()  Time elapsed: 0.002 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.*.air.supply.*.*.drools.ruleengine.ApplyQueryValueThrottleEngineUnitTest.testKnowledgeAgentInitialization(ApplyQueryValueThrottleEngineUnitTest.java:145)

com.*.air.supply.*.*.drools.ruleengine.ApplyQueryValueThrottleEngineUnitTest.testNoM*hingRule()  Time elapsed: 0.266 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.*.air.supply.*.*.drools.ruleengine.ApplyQueryValueThrottleEngineUnitTest.testNoM*hingRule(ApplyQueryValueThrottleEngineUnitTest.java:124)

com.*.air.supply.*.*.drools.ruleengine.ApplyQueryValueThrottleEngineUnitTest.testM*hingRule()  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.*.air.supply.*.*.drools.ruleengine.ApplyQueryValueThrottleEngineUnitTest.testM*hingRule(ApplyQueryValueThrottleEngineUnitTest.java:135)

Comment: All we know is that there is an NPE at line 149 of some class. We have no information on the contents of that line, or on the stacktrace of the exception. How do you expect us to help?

Comment: @yole i am extending the logs of my failed tests.  These tests fails while running clover2:instrument

Comment: Still no stacktrace, still no code, still can't help.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in Clover's 4.0 release notes, Clover 4.x is binary incompatible with Clover 3.x. Therefore you have to ensure that you don't instrument code using Clover 3.x and at the same providing Clover 4.x JAR at runtime (and vice versa).

In particular, ensure that neither your build workspace nor ~/.m2 local cache contain JAR files instrumented by wrong Clover version - a leftover from previous builds.

Run 'mvn clean' in your workspace. Delete all '*-clover.jar' files from ~/.m2. In case you were using 'clover2:setup' together with Maven's 'install' goal, remove also JAR files without '-clover' suffix in their name containing instrumented code (How to recognize if a JAR contains instrumented code? It will have *.class files containing '$__CLR' in their names).

See also:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/Clover+4.0+Release+Notes